# How to enable building UMD bundle again with Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, umd

We have a JavaScript library and for building we use an Angular library project workspace.
This JavaScript library  is not consumed by an Angular application. Actually we need the output to be in UMD format. When I upgraded Angular to 13, I found that this output is not built anymore.

I tried to find a way to enable building the UMD bundle again but was not able to.
I checked:

- https://angular.io/guide/angular-package-format#angular-package-format
- https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr

I understand that for Angular libraries in general it is a very good thing that UMD format is not built anymore but we would still need the UMD format.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
Many thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: We're experiencing the current issue, were you able to manage to find the solution for this?

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer Well actually we were not able to solve it with Angular. We replaced the Angular project with a normal TypeScript project setup. It uses the following tools directly: typescript, rollup, jest, eslint.

Comment: Oh i see, FWIW if you're still interested in learning the workaround in the context of Angular. There seems to be a way to generate UMD files in Angular 13 shared on this github issues thread.
https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/314#issuecomment-1089107900.

Btw, the workaround also uses rollup.