# Angular 16 - How to dynamically import an Angular fesm module library unknown at compile time

Tags: angular, plugins

Sice Angular 13, when you generate a library from angular cli,the only formats supported are esm and fesm.
I'd like to know if there is a way to import fsem module libraries at runtime, without knowing them at compile time.
In the past there was the possibility to use umd, but now this format is no longer supported.
I developed a plugin system that let you add functionalities to the main application without having to repompile all the source code. Moreover, plugins can be developed and compiled independently by third parties.

I checked module federation: it let me compile and deploy the modules independently from the main application, but the main application must know about them at compile time.
I also checked this thread: [How to enable building UMD bundle again with Angular 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70943196/how-to-enable-building-umd-bundle-again-with-angular-13) but it seems complicated and don't know if it's a complete solution to my problem.